Dax - Trouble to convert negative duration in hh:mm:ss
I am facing a problem with a dax to hh:mm:ss conversion for a negative duration value (-0,0118055555555556)
the result I get if I convert the value is -1:17:00 where I should get -00:17:00
with the same dax mesure i obtain different result depending if the duration or negative
if I convert a positive value I get the correct result (00:17:00)
but if it is a negative value, the conversion adds 1 hour less ( -1:17:0 instead of -0:17:0 )
here is the dax formula i use for conversion ( delta is the column with all duration value ( positive and negative )
    Delta Horaire = 
    var _sum = sum('Pointage'[Delta])
    VAR hours =  INT( _sum * 24 )
    VAR Minutes = MINUTE(_sum)
    VAR Seconds = SECOND(_sum)
    RETURN
    Hours & ":" & Minutes & ":" & Seconds

Do you know what cause this and how to correct it?

you can try this
Delta Horaire =
VAR _sum =
    SUM ( 'Table'[delta] )
VAR hours =
    INT ( _sum * 24 )
VAR Minutes =
    MINUTE ( _sum )
VAR Seconds =
    SECOND ( _sum )
RETURN
    IF (
        hours = -1,
        "-" & hours + 1 & ":" & Minutes & ":" & Seconds,
        IF (
            hours < 0,
            hours + 1 & ":" & Minutes & ":" & Seconds,
            hours & ":" & Minutes & ":" & Seconds
        )
    )



thank you for your answer, i knew it should be something with IF but i'm still strugling with how to write in DAX.
With your change i obtain the correct result and correct total except in one case.
For some reason the value showing in the visual sometime don't have the minus sign, even if the value is correctly counted as a négative in the total .
for example :
-1:33:0 become 0:33:0 instead of -0:33:0
-1:53:0 become 0:53:0 instead of -0:53:0
it seem to only happen when the result of the conversion is -0:xx:x
the others result at -1:xx:x ,work fine

updated the solution, pls have a try

Hello thank you it work
